# Display the & character as &

Tags: html

Im trying to display the `&` character as its written. But it keeps converting to special symbol in html.

Example : shoutcast song title

```
Chas & Dave
```

will displayed as `Chas`.

Anything after the `&` wont display.

Comment: i fixed it with this............. $xml = html_entity_decode($xml);
$xml = str_replace("&", "and", str_replace("&#x27;", "'", $xml));

Answer (score 1):

You should write `&amp;` as specified here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp

Comment: i dont think i explained my self very well sorry about that. Maybe this well help... $xml = str_replace("&#x27;", "'", $xml);   i want to add replace & as well to display & not special code.. cheers

Answer (score 1):

`&` has a special meaning in HTML, it means the start of an 'entity'. To output a & itself, use the entity `&amp;`. There are 5 entities common to HTML and XML, `&amp;`, `&lt;` (<), `&gt;` (>), `&quot;` (") and `&apos;` ('), although the last two are often only necessary in attribute values.

HTML has many others, a common one is `&nbsp;`, which is short for 'non-breaking space', often used to force a table cell to display.